# How can I prevent disk UUID mismatch when cloning a machine?

Tags: debian, fstab, uuid

I have built a Debian linux machine.
I have captured an 'image' of the entire hard drive in the form of a compressed tar file.
I then unpack this onto another machine, setting up grub so that it can boot.

The problem I encounter is that the disk UUID differs from that from the original and therefore, the disk is mounted as read-only. I can fix this afterwards by configuring the correct UUID in /etc/fstab
However, I would like to avoid this.

What can I do on the original machine BEFORE I capture an 'image' of it, so that when unpacked to another machine this problem is avoided?

Update: Based on useful commentary to one of the answers, I should clarify that the initial machine and subsequent clone/s will only ever have a single disk.

Comment: If you use a tar file, that's more like copying the individual files on the filesystem (not the whole drive). If the machines are identical enough, you could also copy the full drive, which would mean you wouldn't need the extra step of setting up grub, etc. On the downside, all the clones would have the same UUID, and if you ever plugged them in the same machine, that could cause problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do on the original machine BEFORE I capture an 'image' of it, so that when unpacked to another machine this problem is avoided?

instead of the disk reference being mount by-name, do it by

- mounted **by-label**
- or mounted **by-name**

---

```
# for example when mounted by-name it would look like this in /etc/fstab

/dev/sda3   /

# and When mounted by-label it would like this in /etc/fstab

LABEL=some_name   /
```

Doing it **by-label** would work in a new system with no extra work needed.

Know that doing it **by-name** will only work in a new system if it is the only disk in the system such that it guarantees its reference to be `sda`.  When there are other disks in the system, or whenever other hardware is treated as `/dev/sd?`, you cannot rely on your cloned disk always being `sda` and that's where the problem with by-name is.  If all your `/etc/fstab` and `grub` references have `/dev/sda` but your disk comes in as `/dev/sdb` well then **boot device not found**.

You have to know your Linux system a little bit, RHEL/CentOS, SLES/SUSE, Ubuntu, or whatever else, **and find where all the disk references are**.  It's not just `/etc/fstab`.  The **Grub** boot loader is most likely to be the other places, as it is the most popular among Linux's.  Story: I used to use SLES 11 which used ELILO... which was an alternative to grub, which I thought was great... bring back ELILO ! ... but for that I only needed to worry about **one** other file besides `/etc/fstab` which was `elilo.conf`.

Once your newly cloned disk is booted and running, then among your various tasks of setting up that new system (hostname, ip address, etc) just update `/etc/fstab` and the grub files to go back to mount by-uuid

Also know that for mount **by-label** it is on you to guarantee no other disks use the same label.  Seems simply enough, but it is easy to forget; for example I always label the `/boot` partition simply `boot` and my `/` partition simply `root`.  If I go and clone disks then try to have two of those disks connected and try to boot, which does the system choose when more than one *partition* has the same label?  So by-label can bite you if you're forgetful... the system can easily boot and work but you will not be running on the disk you think you are.

Look under `/dev/disk/` and you will see

- by-id/
- by-label/
- by-partlabel/
- by-partuuid/
- by-path/
- by-uuid/

use that for reference, it should be very clear to understand.

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label

lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Mar  2 15:46 boot -> ../../sdc2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Mar  2 15:46 data -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Mar  2 15:46 root -> ../../sdc3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Mar  2 15:46 scratch -> ../../sdb1

# Explanation of these 4 listings: when installing Linux I always do
    /boot    ==> /dev/sda2  labeled as 'boot'
    /        ==> /dev/sdc3  labeled as 'root'
   
  my other disks here on this specific system I labeled as data and scratch.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `blkid` to find out the original partitions UUIDs.
2. For ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions use `sudo tune2fs -U UUID /dev/partition` to set the UUID which you got in 1.

- For btrfs it will be `sudo btrfstune -U UUID /dev/partition`
- For xfs it will be `sudo xfs_admin -U UUID /dev/partition`

Beware that it's *not* advisable to have different partitions with [the same UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and doubly so if you decide to plug in two disks in the same PC. Your kernel and you personally may get confused and something unintended may happen.

Comment: that is so much worse and so much more work than just editing /etc/fstab - which is the **correct** thing to do.  the untarred fs IS on a different partition with a different UUID, so /etc/fstab **should** be edited to reflect the new reality.

Comment: @cas Everyone can have their own opinion (as long as this opinion doesn't harm other people's lives) and I cannot say the OP wants to do something incorrect. As for me personally I use `e2image` for this purpose - it helps preserve files' atime's which is quite difficult otherwise. Also I love keeping track of my FS for as long as possible including their creating time and bytes written.

Comment: Some things are just matters of opinion.  Making a UUID non-unique is unquestionably a bad idea.  Hint: it's in the name Universally Unique ID - it's meant to be unique.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: And if an OP wants to do something that's just plain wrong, a responsible answer or comment will inform them of that fact, not just merrily help them load and aim the gun at their foot.

Comment: The OP made it clear he's working with *different physically separated devices*, so while I agree with your considerations I don't think it's a sin not to follow them. Also you may remember people didn't even use UUIDs > 10 years ago and no one complained. There's nothing *plain wrong* in what they are doing. You might be overreacting.

Comment: "no one complained"?  you do realise that there's a reason why UUIDs were invented, right?  to solve real problems that real people were actually having.

Comment: Again, not that *many* people had those problems and again the OP is talking about *different physically separated devices*. **I've added your considerations to the answer**.